# Python decorator - Trying to understand a simple example

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to understand python decorators.
I devised that simple example where I want the decorator function to be a custom log that just print error if for instance I try to sum_  and `int` and a `str`

```
def log(fun):
    try:
        return fun(*args)
    except:
        print('error!')        

@log
def sum_(a,b):
    return a+b
```

This returns `"error"` already simply when I define the function. I suspect there are multiple wrong things in what I did... I tried to look into the other questions about that topic, but I find them all to intricate to understand how such a simple example should be drafted ,esp how to pass the arguments from the original function.

All help and pointers appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is simply because `args` is undefined in your decorator. This isn't anything special about decorators, just a regular `NameError`. For this reason you probably want to restrict your exception clause to just `TypeError`s so that you're not silencing other errors. A full implementation would be

```
import functools

def log(fun):
    @functools.wraps(fun)
    def inner(*args):
        try:
            return fun(*args)
        except TypeError:
            print('error!')
    return inner

@log
def sum_(a, b):
    return a + b
```

It's also a good idea to decorate your inner functions with the `functools.wrap` decorator, which transfers the name and docstring from your original function to your decorated one.

Comment: @DSM Good catch, should be fixed now.

Comment: @iafisher thanks, this is useful. regarding `functools.wraps`, the name of the function is already transfered anyway with the variable `fun` no? So it really only trasnsfer the docstring doesnt it?

Comment: @jimbasquiat Comment out the `@functools.wrap(fun)` line and then put `print(sum_.__name__)` at the bottom of the file. You'll see `inner` instead of `sum_`.

Comment: @iafisher ok i see . what is that `__name__` variable used for usually? aside from the `if __name__ =='__main__' ?

Comment: It can be useful for debugging purposes. For example, if you have a higher order function that takes another function as an argument `f`, then you can do `print(f.__name__)` to see what function is being passed on a particular call.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from my post and ran it. `sum_(1, 'a')` prints `error!` instead of raising an exception, as expected. Both in Python 3.4 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're not forwarding the `args` from the function to your decorator, and the *catch-all* exception *catches* the `NameError` for `args`; one of the reasons to always specify the exception class.

Here's a modified version of your code with the try-catch removed and the function arguments correctly forwarded:

```
def log(fun):
    def wrapper(*args):
          print('in decorator!')
          return fun(*args)
    return wrapper

@log
def sum_(a,b):
    return a+b

print sum_(1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `log` decorator, in this case, does not return a function, but a value. This may point on an assumption that the decorator function replaces the original function, where in fact, it is called to create a replacement function.

A fix which may represent the intention:

```
def log(fun):
    def my_func(*args):
        try:
            return fun(*args)
        except:
            print('error!')

    return my_func
```

In this case, `my_func` is the actual function which is called for `sum_(1, 2)`, and internally, it calls the original function (the original `sum_`) which the decorator received as an argument.

A trivial example that illustrates the order of the actions:

```
def my_decorator(fun):
    print 'This will be printed first, during module load'
    def my_wrapper(*args):
        print 'This will be printed during call, before the original func'
        return fun(*args)

    return my_wrapper()

@my_decorator
def func():
    print('This will be printed in the original func')
```